# Running a AS3 function from inside a htmlloader object triggered by several links <a>

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Using this code im able to run ONE AS3 function from a click event on a link inside the content loaded in my HtmlLoader:

**The html loaded content:**

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <a href="#" id="testLink">Click me.</a> 
</html>
```

The AS3

```
var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader( ); 
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.html"); 
html.load(urlReq); 
html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 

function completeHandler(event:Event):void { 
    html.window.document.getElementById("testLink").onclick = clickHandler; 
} 

function clickHandler( event:Object ):void { 
    trace("Event of type: " + event.type ); 
}
```

The problem now is, I want to pass parameters to the clickHandler function from the html content, and also I want to have several links:

```
<a class="fireAS3" href="someData1">bla bla bla</a>
<a class="fireAS3" href="someData2">bla bla bla</a>
<a class="fireAS3" href="someData3">bla bla bla</a>
```

so using Ids is not an option, I guess i need classes but using getElementByIdClassName gives me an error (function does not exist). So, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You could use the `LocationChangeEvent` to do opposite JS->AS3 "conversation" this way you could prepare the links in such a way that will provide loads of arguments passed using JSON. Folloowing is an excerpt from my program that renders long list within the `StageWebView` (`HTMLLoader` has the same event) and get back click events with some details about it:

```
webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, onWebLocationUpdate, false, 0, true);
webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onWebLocationUpdate, false, 0, true);

protected function onWebLocationUpdate(e:LocationChangeEvent):void
{
   trace(e);
    //JS->AS
    if (e.location.indexOf("message://") != -1)
    {
        var jsonString:String = e.location.substr("message://".length);
        var myObject:Object = JSON.parse( jsonString );
        for (var name:String in myObject)
        {
            trace(name + ":" + myObject[name]);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // do something here
    //alert("Ready");
    $(".rowItem").click(function(e)
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("rowItemSelected");
        $(this).bridgeSend($(this).attr("id"),$(this).hasClass("rowItemSelected"));
    });
});

(function( $ ){
    $.fn.bridgeSend = function(id, selected)
    {
        var method = "select";
        var json = "{\"item\":{\"selected\":"+selected+",\"name\":\""+id+"\"},\"method\":\""+method+"\"}";
        window.location = "message://"+json;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

HTML

```
    <div class="rowItem" id="entry2">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="icon"><img src="css/clock.png" /></div>
            <div class="date"><h3>Fri, 04-09-2010</h3></div>
        </div><!-- end of the top -->
        <div class="desc">
            <p><strong>Title</strong></p>
            <p>The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
        </div><!-- end of the desc -->
        <div class="times">
            <div class="col1">09:00</div>
            <div class="col2">09:30</div>
            <div class="col3">0.50</div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end of the rowItem -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For easy communication between air and js, i think u can easily use RichWebView ANE that we have coded https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE